# Fedora 36 - Docker - Cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fedora

**OS: Fedora 36**

I noticed this when my docker containers stopped working out of the blue. Fedora said the docker-compose stopped working. After system updates and a restart, I did the following:

```
sudo service docker start
```

Which worked, as I then did `sudo service docker status`

```
redirecting to /bin/systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor p>
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-09-14 10:29:01 MDT; 1s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 2778 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 22
     Memory: 114.0M
        CPU: 347ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─ 2778 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/con>

Sep 14 10:29:00 fedora dockerd[2778]: time="2022-09-14T10:29:00.385376990-06:00>
Sep 14 10:29:00 fedora dockerd[2778]: time="2022-09-14T10:29:00.439821904-06:00>
Sep 14 10:29:00 fedora dockerd[2778]: time="2022-09-14T10:29:00.696795461-06:00>
Sep 14 10:29:00 fedora dockerd[2778]: time="2022-09-14T10:29:00.839972916-06:00>
Sep 14 10:29:00 fedora dockerd[2778]: time="2022-09-14T10:29:00.895624616-06:00>
Sep 14 10:29:00 fedora dockerd[2778]: time="2022-09-14T10:29:00.994809032-06:00>
Sep 14 10:29:01 fedora dockerd[2778]: time="2022-09-14T10:29:01.017873180-06:00>
Sep 14 10:29:01 fedora dockerd[2778]: time="2022-09-14T10:29:01.018007624-06:00>
Sep 14 10:29:01 fedora systemd[1]: Started docker.service - Docker Application >
Sep 14 10:29:01 fedora dockerd[2778]: time="2022-09-14T10:29:01.035944310-06:00>
```

So I can see it is working, it is running. I ran this again five minutes later, same result.

Next I ran `docker ps -a` and got:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
> unix:///home/XXXXX/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon
> running?

Which is odd, so next I checked who owns the docker.sock:

```
sudo ls -la /var/run/docker.sock

srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Sep 14 10:29 /var/run/docker.sock
```

For some reason its owned by root, so I decided to change it my user:

```
sudo chown XXXXX:docker /var/run/docker.sock
```

Now it shows as me: XXXXX:docker - blanked out user name:

```
srw-rw---- 1 XXXXX docker 0 Sep 14 10:29 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Now we stop and start again, as above. As above it is also running after doing `sudo service docker status`

Now if I try and do `docker ps -a` I still get:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
> unix:///home/XXXXX/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker
> daemon running?

I have googled, and I have searched, but I am so confused, docker is running - but apparently it's not running?

**How do I fix this?**

The only thing I can think of is blowing away docker completely and re-installing, but that seems drastic.

Every where I look its:

- Make sure its running - check
- Change owner/group of of the sock file - done
- restart docker - done
- Check status - done

Another thing that I stumbled upon was:

`sudo dockerd`

Which gave me a bunch of output but at the end it was:

> failed to start daemon: error while opening volume store metadata
> database: timeout

Comment: Do you have a `DOCKER_SOCK` environment variable set, and if so, does unsetting it help?  Have you tried to use Docker Desktop on this system?

Comment: @DavidMaze I do not, for the environment variable. But, using docker desktop works. I am able to start the app, then everything works, then I close the app and everything still works. Not sure why the app it's self makes things work. But for now it seems like a work around, not a good one for an answer. Can you tell me more about this environment variable?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also running Fedora 36.

Docker is looking in your home directory for `docker.sock`

`/home/XXXXX/.docker/desktop/docker.sock`
This is most likely because you had / still have docker desktop installed.
If you remove docker desktop there is a possibility that the .docker folder would still be present in your home directory. When reinstalling the docker engine instead of installing docker desktop the daemon would still try and connect to the docker.sock in the aboce directory.

I had the same problem and solved it by doing the following:

- Uninstall Docker Desktop
- Unistall Docker Engine as per the installation guide
- delete the ***.docker*** folder `rm -R ~/.docker`
- Continue installing docker engine as per the installation guide
- Add your user to the docker group `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
- Do one of the following inorder to tell the terminal the group has updated
- run `newgrp docker`
- OR Logout out and log back in of your machine
- OR Restart your machine
- Run `docker run hello-world` to confirm if its working now

The above was what fixed the issue on my machine and there is always the possibility that our setups arent exactly the same.

Comment: What if we want to work with Docker Desktop?